# How do I disable suppressing a warning for one solution in a TFS build

Tags: c#, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2010 and have a TFS build setup to build our software. Everything is working just fine.

But, we are getting the following warning:

```
CSC: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
```

This is because some of our code is marked as x86 only, and it is being built on an x64 platform.  We cannot change the target platform because of third party software we link to.
Also we are targeting the 2.0 framework, which also cannot be changed at this point.

So, I want to simply suppress this error. Seems straight forward enough. 
I simply edited the Build template, and added /p:NoWarn=1607. That works.

BUT!

We have ONE solution which is written in VB.net, instead of C#.  This causes that one solution to fail with the following error:

```
vbc: warning number '1607' for the option nowarn is either not configurable or not valid
```

How do I disable suppressing this warning on that one solution in my TFS build?
I tried to use a `<customPropertiesForBuild>` tag in my TFSBuild.proj file but I'm probably not using it correctly.

I know I could simply add this to my project files, but we have 37 solutions, each with multiple project files, so I really don't want to do that.

Comment: Are you listing the solutions (including the VB solution) in the TFSBuild.proj file, as **SolutionToBuild** items, or are you using the Default build process template and listing the solutions in the build definition?

Comment: They are listed as SolutionToBuild items.

Comment: You should be able to use the **Properties** metadata on the VB solution's **SolutionToBuild** item. See my answer below for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use **Properties** metadata on the VB solution's **SolutionToBuild** item to set NoWarn to an empty value just for that solution:

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../MyVbSolution.sln">
  <Targets></Targets>
  <Properties>NoWarn=;</Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

Try that and see if your VB solution will compile without errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can control that suppression from TFS since it is MSbuild complaining during build (and TFS simply calls MSBuild and collects the results).

There's a specific property that tells msbuild to ignore this kind of warning. Simply add the following line to your top `Propertygroup` in the project file for those projects generating the warning:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried putting this in my TFSBuild.proj file and it did not suppress the warning. Maybe you meant put this in the project file of those which are generating the error? I'll try that next.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a NoWarn Property to MSbuild in TFS Build. One idea also is to edit the build definition, in the "Process" Tab, explore the Advanced=>MSBuild Arguments, and then you supply this "/p:NoWarn=1607" without the qoutes. When you also queue a build, in Parameters Tab=>Advanced=>MSBuild Arguments, enter/p:NoWarn=1607.

Comment: Doing this does indeed suppress the errors. The issue is that doing this causes the VB solution to fail building.